# How to prove this inequality? If $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive real numbers.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive real numbers, then
> $$
>   \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}
>   ≥
>   \sqrt{\frac{a^2 + 1}{b^2 + 1}}
>   + \sqrt{\frac{b^2 + 1}{c^2 + 1}}
>   + \sqrt{\frac{c^2 + 1}{a^2 + 1}} \,.
> $$

I can see that
$$
  \frac{a^2 + b^2 + 2}{ \sqrt{(a^2+1) (b^2+1)} }
  =
  \sqrt{\frac{a^2 + 1}{b^2 + 1}}
  + \sqrt{\frac{b^2 + 1}{a^2+ 1 }}
$$
and
$$
  \sqrt{(a ^ 2 + 1)(b ^ 2 + 1)} ≥ ab + 1 \,.
$$

But I can't make any progress. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An interesting algebraic inequality involving a square root](/questions/2824213/an-interesting-algebraic-inequality-involving-a-square-root) - found using an  [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Ba%7D%5Cge%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7Bb%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bb%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7Bc%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bc%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7Ba%5E%7B2%7D%2B1%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%2C%20OR%20content%3Areal&p=1).

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, that search also found the AoPS thread [a,b,c>0 involve a/b+b/c+c/a... ineq sm14](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h604098p3587355), where your problem, and solutions to it, start at [Post #$9$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h604098p3680922). Also, the problem is listed, among quite a few other related ones, in the AoPS thread [Lemma about a/b + b/c + c/a](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1892179p12914870).

Comment: @John Omielan Thank you sir. The links you gave are very helpful. Thanks.